# How to delete element from database realm Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I need to delete elements from the database.
That's my code and I don't know if I am right

```
        realm.executeTransaction(
                realm1 -> {
                    
                        RealmResults<UserWordRealm> result = realm1.where(UserWordRealm.class).equalTo("id",id).findAll();
                        result.deleteAllFromRealm();

                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to delete all the elements in your table, or just one element? I'm asking because you are using an ID in your query, but also executing findAll().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RealmObject class, the id(PrimaryKey) field must uniquely identify the object. Therefore, there cannot be more than one element with the same id. Using `findFirst()` instead of `findAll()` may solve your problem.

To delete an object from a realm, use either the dynamic or static versions of the `deleteFromRealm()` method of a RealmObject subclass.

```
realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
    UserWordRealm userWordObject = r.where(UserWordRealm.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    userWordObject.deleteFromRealm();
    // discard the reference
    userWordObject = null;
});
```